# Curve and Constant Curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, algebraic-curves, curvature

I have initial position vector $p_0$,  given curve-linear  length $1$. It can be parameterized  by $s\in[0,1]$. Assume we have the equation to generate the curve from given starting point and constant curvature through out the length as $p(s)=\psi(p_0,{K}_{3 \times 1},s)$, where K is the curvature vector.(You can take it as cosserat rod modeling).

It implies if I take constant $K_0$ as curvature I may get $p(s)$ a different value at s compared when I take $K_1$ for s. Now the question is I am having a curve in the same starting point on same curvelinear length,but its curvature is varying on s as $K_v(s)=(1-s)K_0+sK_1$.  What we know is that curve point is some where   between $\psi(p_0,{K_0},s)$ and $\psi(p_0,{K_1},s)$. We are equipped with readymade $\psi$.

**Question**

How can we find the points on new curve whose curvature is a linear interpolation of $K_0$ and $K_1$ from the given $\psi$

NB :: This is not Frenet-Serret Model, it is Cosserat model of curve. The difference is we bend across two cross sectional axices too.  Please click [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5739v1.pdf) for the pdf where the details of the cosserat curve given at  page 4.